# How to extract substring from a string in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a string like:

```
oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

I want to extract these values into three variables.

Can you please suggest the easiest method in ColdFusion?

Comment: I am guessing you are trying to implement authentication by Facebook,twitter or Google. Usually these kind of services responses in JSON format. You might want to look into deserializeJSON. You can deserialize your http.filecontent and use that struct to get values of all three variables.

Comment: @ Tushar Bhaware : I am trying to integrate with Xero but I am getting the file content as string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Dan Bracuk was close, this will do what you want.

```
<cfset myString = "oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true">
<cfloop list="#myString#" index="pair" delimiters="&">
    <cfset myStruct[ListFirst(pair, "=")] = ListLast(pair, "=")>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#myStruct#">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
<cfloop 
list = "oauth_token=xxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true"      
index="pair" delimiter="&">
<cfset ListFirst(pair, "=") = ListLast(pair, "=")>
</cfloop>
```

I'm not sure if it work, but it would be worth a shot.

Comment: I am getting the error 'Attribute delimiter is not allowed for tag cfloop'

Comment: @user3270746 - The attribute name is "delimiters" (plural) not "delimiter" (singular).

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative to the accepted solution:

```
<cfset t = "oauth_token=abc&oauth_token_secret=def&oauth_callback_confirmed=true">
    <cfset oauth_token = ListGetAt(ListGetAt(t,1,"&"),2,"=")>
    <cfset oauth_token_secret = ListGetAt(ListGetAt(t,2,"&"),2,"=")>
    <cfset oauth_callback_confirmed = ListGetAt(ListGetAt(t,3,"&"),2,"=")>
```

Comment: Worth noting that this does assume that the string returned is always in the same order

Comment: @JohnWhish, true. I didn't consider the possibility of string returning in other order than mentioned.